# Why does the $PSVersionTable.BuildVersion output differs from that of [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version?

Tags: windows, powershell, version

Why does the `$PSVersionTable.BuildVersion` output :

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.BuildVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      19041  2673


PS C:\>
```

differs from that of `[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version` ? :

```
PS C:\> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      19045  0


PS C:\>
```

Which one is more reliable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a bit of digging, and the `BuildVersion` entry in `$PSVersionTable` in Windows PowerShell 5.1 comes from the `System.Management.Automation.dll` - the assembly containing all of PowerShell's language and engine features.

In other words: it's the *assembly* version, not the Operating System version that's reflected in `$PSVersionTable['BuildVersion']` - and they might not be *aligned* since the assembly may have been replaced by a security update outside the lifecycle updates to the OS itself and vice-versa.

You can discover the assembly version directly like this:

```
$SMAVersionInfo = Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath ([psobject].Assembly.Location) -Name VersionInfo
$SMAProductVersion = [version]$SMAVersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

`$SMAProductVersion` should now have the exact same value as `$PSVersionTable['BuildVersion']`